# How to add percentage text box with decimal and percentage sign using Telerik RadControls

Tags: input, telerik, decimal, percentage

How can I add a percentage textbox with **decimal** and **percentage sign** using Telerik RadControls?

I mean Telerik `MaskedTextBox` or Telerik `NumericTextBox`?

Which one and how?

I wrote the aspx code below :

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="RadNumerictxtPercent_Taliya" runat="server"
                Type="Percent" Width="60px" EnableEmbeddedSkins="False" Skin="BlackByMe" ValidationGroup="C"
                MaxValue="20" MinValue="0">
                <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="2" ZeroPattern="n %" />
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

but I can not increase and decrease percentage (decimal area) using keyborad!

Also it seems there is a problem about percentage sign in that aspx code!

How can I fix them?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2"

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="RadNumericTextBox1" runat="server" Type="Percent"
    Width="60px" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2" MaxValue="20" MinValue="0">
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```